# Simple Zpl printing not working?

Tags: php, zebra-printers, zpl, zpl-ii

I have this in test.txt

```
CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTT^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR6,6~SD15^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ^XA^MMT^PW508^LL0203^LS0^BY4,3,138^FT48,155^BCN,,Y,N^FD>;12^FS^PQ1,0,1,Y^XZ
```

and I use the Zpl printer Google chrome add-on

On my mac in terminal I tried (after some ls)

```
lp -d zpl test.txt
```

All i get is 26 labels with error messages

```
ERROR: requested label 0, but there are only 0 labels
```

I also tried

```
lp -d zpl test.txt -o position=top-left,ppi=203,landscape
```

still 26 labels

But I expected something like this (but I have different label dimensions)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Few things I can find in your code.

Firstly 
CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~^XA~TA000~JSN^LT0^MNW^MTT^PON^PMN^LH0,0^JMA^PR6,6~SD15^JUS^LRN^CI0^XZ^

This is an invalid label and the XA and XZ are telling the printer that this is one label (you really have two labels above, 2 pairs XA to start and XZ to end). Put just that part in an online zpl viewer and you will see the invalid with the same error. Your data is actually in the second portion of your code. Take out the middle ^XZ and ^XA and leave the first ^XA and ending ^XZ. Your code should work then.

Also FYI you don't need CT~~CD,~CC^~CT~ along with much of other parts of your code. These commands are telling the printer to change the control characters, however you telling them to change them to the default. example CT = change tilde then you put to tilde, and CC = change carot to carot etc.....